# How to deploy windows services using MSBuild?

Tags: c#, msbuild, windows-services, continuous-integration

I have created a windows service project using Visual Studio which needs to be installed on to the remote machine using MSBuild. I have had a look at lots of resources on good ways of deploying windows services. Most answer were using PowerShell scripts which i think of as an alternative.

Can anyone provide me with good resource. Any ideas on how to deploy this. There are lots of security issues with deploying (.exe) files in enterprise environment so i am worried on picking any alternatives.

I will really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: **MSBuild** is the build system for Visual Studio. You need [Windows Installer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer)

Comment: Its a visual studio solution containing setup files

Comment: MSBuild is the tool to compile and build any solution in Visual Studio.  You can't use it to install anything.  Add a Setup project to your solution with the Windows Service and use the output of the Setup project to install on your remote machine.

Comment: msbuild is much broader than just the VS build system. It is not restricted to VS. But that doesn't change the fact that you don't deploy with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Exec Task (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) look at the link.

Using powershell remoting would be another option for sure.

Answer (score 3):

you can use MSBuild
example for install:

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Computer.WindowsService TaskAction="Install" ServiceName="SomeWindowsService" User="UserLocal" Password="PassLocal" ServicePath="\\RemoteComp2\PathForYourService\WindowsService.exe" RemoteUser="UserRemoteComp2" RemoteUserPassword="PassRemoteComp2" MachineName="RemoteComp2"/>
```

for more information look follow link http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.5.0/html/258a18b7-2cf7-330b-e6fe-8bc45db381b9.htm

Answer (score 0):

To install service to the remote machine you can try ServiceController task that can control a Windows service. From [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/12/438061.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at PSExec (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) depending on your requirements and deployment scenario.  It, combined with the MSBuild Exec task, would allow you to install the service remotely.

Comment: I got remote paths (\\<server>\<whatever>\<it.exe> in my service when I used this method